# Linkbutton click opens modalpopup, Browser back button leads to "Document expired"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a very sensitive unresolved bug for me.
Pls look at this [forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/2055720.aspx?AjaxToolKit%20ModalPopup%20Linkbutton%20click%20opens%20modalpopup%20Browser%20back%20button%20leads%20to%20Document%20expired%20ASP%20NET%20C%20),

on asp:linkbutton click a modalPop will be opened, upon this if back button is clicked, browsers says "Document expired"

Linkbutton is added dynamically inside the gridview and the command also, on click of dynamically added linkbutton "lnkBtnBookTheSelected_Click" function will be called there i'm capturing the selected row ID.

```
bool CheckAvailability()
{
   //some logical code and getting data in "statusList"
   Session["Availability"] = statusList;
   gridViewAvailability_DataBound(null,null);
}

protected void gridViewAvailability_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[]  statusList = (string[])Session["Availability"];
   try
   {

        if (statusList.Length > 0)
        {
             int i = 1;
             foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewAvailability.Rows)
             {
                 row.Cells[3].Controls.Clear();
                 if (statusList[i - 1] == "Available")
                 {
                      LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                      lb.Text = "Book this?";
                      lb.CommandArgument =i.ToString();            
lb.Command+=lnkBtnBookTheSelected_Click;                                                             
                      row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lb);

             }
             else
             {
                  Label lbl = new Label();
                  lbl.Text ="Not available";
                  row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lbl);
             }

         }
         i++;
     }

}
catch (Exception a)
{

}
}

protected void lnkBtnBookTheSelected_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{    
     Session["SelectedID"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();    
     lblUserMsgForPurpose.Text = "Dear " + Session["UserName"].ToString() + ", Please enter for what purpose you want to Booking";
     ModalPopupExtenderPurpose.Show();//popup for some input                   
}
```

Comment: Using LinkButton to openPopup in client side is quite bad idea..
for your desire, You can send ajaxRequest to server in order to save variables in session. and open the popup as soon as request ended

Answer (score 0):

The "Document Expired" message from the browser is likely being caused by hitting back after POSTing the form (the postback on click).

I would suggest calling show on the ModalPopupExtender via Javascript, instead of doing a full postback.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function showPopup() {
      $find('ModalPopupExtenderPurpose').show();
   }
</script>
```

Then, in your LinkButton tag, add onlick='showPopup();return 0;'

```
<asp:LinkButton runat='server' id='lnkBtnBookTheSelected' Text='Show Popup' onclick='showPopup();return 0;' />
```

You can manipulate any other HTML that you need to when it opens in the same javascript function.

Comment: Query is further more detailed, The code provided works with normally added link button, Here LinkButton is dynamically added into a Gridview and on click the ID is captured like "protected void lnkBtnBookTheSelected_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)" 

As shown in updated question.
how to do this in JavaScript, This is the only bug due to which deployment is stopped.